# Why the first item of my ComboBox always empty

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I have searched a long time in stackoverflow and MSDN, I'm not sure why the marked answer works for others but doesn't work for me.

I have a City class like this

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static List<City> GetDefaultCities()
    {
        List<City> cities = new List<City>();
        cities.Add(new City { Id = 1, Name = "New York" });
        cities.Add(new City { Id = 2, Name = "Chicago" });
        cities.Add(new City { Id = 3, Name = "Miami" });
        cities.Add(new City { Id = 4, Name = "Houston" });
        cities.Add(new City { Id = 5, Name = "Dallas" });

        return cities;
    }
}
```

The properties in my ViewModel:

```
private List<City> cities;
    public List<City> Cities
    {
        get { return City.GetDefaultCities(); }
        set { cities = value; }
    }

    private City selectedCity;
    public City SelectedCity
    {
        get { return selectedCity; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedCity != value)
            {
                selectedCity = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCity");
            }
        }
    }
```

The XAML in my View

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" Width="100" Height="30"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="Id"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}"
              />
```

I have tried 3 solutions:
1. Set the SelectedIndex as 0 in XAML;
2. Set Text Property as the first element of Cities Name in XAML;
3. Set a default value to City property in ViewModel;

But all of them don't work, the first element always empty. Anybody can help?

Comment: have you tried to bind the selectedvalue instead of the selecteditem to a SelectedId and set the SelectedId via vm?

Comment: @dnr3, couldn't please provide more details? How to set SelectedId in vm

Comment: I mean you create another property in your vm named SelectedId to bind to the SelectedValue of the ComboBox, because the SelectedItem of the combobox probably not the one you're looking for (the value probably is a ComboBoxItem and not an instance of City)

Comment: nevermind my last comment, I just checked and I can also bind the SelectedItem to the SelectedCity and it worked fine, how did you set the selectedCity default value?

Comment: @dnr3, I assign the first element of Cities to the SelectedCity property in constructor

Comment: well then that's the problem, you will have to assign the cities in the constructor too before you select it (so put the City.GetDefaultCities() into constructor), and the Cities property only return cities

Comment: @dnr3, Yeah, great! Thanks! Could you please write it as reply, so that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should construct the list of cities inside the constructor and then assign the selectedCity with the first value of the list

```
public CityListViewModel()
{
    cities = City.GetDefaultCities();
    selectedCity = cities[0];
}
```

and then you just return the already filled list of cities in the Cities property getter

```
public List<City> Cities
{
   get { return cities; }
   set { cities = value; }
}
```